# ROS support on Yocto 3.9.0

Tags: user-interface, embedded-linux, yocto, ros, renesas-rx

I recently acquired a Renesas R Car M3 board which runs on an embedded Linux image built by means of the Yocto project. We are currently using Yocto 3.9.0. We are looking forward to implement ROS kinetic libraries on this embedded Linux. Does the Yocto project support these libraries? In case it does, is there any special process to install and run them, or does it work as a normal Linux distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Yocto has a [meta-ros](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-ros/) layer which adds support to ROS.

There still is an open issue on [meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros/issues/596) layer for Kinetic specific version support, that is partially fixed by the following [fork](https://github.com/bulwahn/meta-ros/tree/kinetic-experimental-v3-alpha1/recipes-ros).

I suggest you to look here how to create standard [Renesas Yocto BSP](https://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Yocto-Gen3), and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded) for ROS.

Comment: Could you tell me then, which version of ROS is stable and without issues for YOCTO 3.9.0? In that case we could change the ROS version we are using so it could run without problems.

Comment: I'm not using ROS anymore but it should be Indigo, which is a bit problematic as it's reaching EOL soon.

Comment: Thank you very much, we will discuss if it is convenient to modify the version of ROS we are using.